# how to inject a property just when kernel finds it

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I have a module that I load it by Kernel when my application starts with the following code:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Load("*.dll");
```

But in some cases I don't want to place the module assembly in bin folder and don't use that module and it corresponding features. Then I have properties in my consumer class that use `[Inject]` attribute. I want to Ninject return null for these properties when it doesn't find it's module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default this code throw an exception if NInject fails to find a dependency.

```
using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel())
{
    kernel.Load("*.dll");
    var someClass = kernel.Get<SomeClassWithDependency>();
    someClass.TryDoSomething();
}
```

To solve this, simply add the `Optional` attribute to the property:

```
public class SomeClassWithDependency
{
    public void TryDoSomething()
    {
        if (SomeType != null)
        {
            SomeType.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    [Inject, Optional]
    public ISomeType SomeType { get; set; }
}
```